# Guard not unwrapping optional

Tags: swift, option-type

I'm trying to process a JSON object, using a `guard` statement to unwrap it and cast to the type I want, but the value is still being saved as an optional.

```
guard let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [String:Any] else {
    break
}

let result = json["Result"]
// Error: Value of optional type '[String:Any]?' not unwrapped
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: You must set parentheses: `(try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: Data())) as? [String:Any]` – I think this has been asked and answered before, but haven't found the duplicate yet, so I might be wrong.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43121890/2303865

Comment: @LeoDabus: I can not see any `try?` in that *question,* or a similar error message.

Comment: `init?(data: Data) {
        guard let json = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data)) as? [String: Any] else { return nil }
        self.init(dictionary: json)
    }`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [String:Any]
```

is interpreted as

```
try? (JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [String:Any])
```

which makes it a "double optional" of type `[String:Any]??`. 
The optional binding removes only one level, so that `json` has
the type `[String:Any]?`

The problem is solved by setting parentheses:

```
guard let json = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data)) as? [String:Any] else {
    break
}
```

And just for fun: Another (less obvious?, obfuscating?) solution is to
use pattern matching with a double optional pattern:

```
guard case let json?? = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [String:Any] else {
    break
}
```

Comment: That fixed the problem, seems weird that it doesn't unwrap it either way though.  Isn't the point of a guard to guarantee that it has a value?

Comment: @JohnMontgomery: For a "nested optional" of type `T??` optional binding checks if the expression has a value (of type `T?`), but that value can be `nil` :) Compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27225232/two-or-more-optionals-in-swift.

Comment: I think I understand the difference there.  Just to make sure: with no parentheses, the `try?` is on the outside, and the `guard` guarantees that it's returning a value but the value is still another optional (which in some cases may be important to distinguish from not returning a value at all).  On the other hand, with the parentheses, the `as?` is on the outside, and since it's trying to cast to a non-optional type the value is non-optional.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery: I would put is a bit differently. `try?` always adds a level of optionality to the expression that it is applied to. On the other hand, a conditional cast `expr as? T`  evaluates to `T?`, even if `expr` already is an optional, so it does not add another level.

Comment: @derpoliuk: Thanks for the edit suggestion. However, I would suggest that you post your solution as a separate answer.