# Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value with API data

Tags: swift, api

I'm new to Swift...

Trying to display some API data from newsapi which was working fine, but after a few runs I started getting the

> Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value error at line 12 (let articles = dataDictionary["results"] as! [[String: Any]])

```
    let url = URL(string: "https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?sources=techcrunch&apiKey=d65fb8f01d8e42c7b106590d09149d39")!

    let request = URLRequest(url: url, cachePolicy: .reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData, timeoutInterval: 10)
    let session = URLSession(configuration: .default, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main)
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in

         //This will run when the network request returns
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        } else if let data = data {
            let dataDictionary = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! [String: Any]
            let articles = dataDictionary["results"] as! [[String: Any]]
            self.articles = articles
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    task.resume()
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Never ever use force unwrap. Also separate your controller from your model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use guard let on this change:-

```
let articles = dataDictionary["results"] as! [[String: Any]]
```

to this line:-

```
guard  let articles = dataDictionary["results"] as? [[String: Any]] else { return}
```

don't use `!` until you sure this must have value

Also see this answer to avoid this `!`:- [Guard not unwrapping optional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43123036/guard-not-unwrapping-optional)

Answer (score 1):

Your `dataDictionary` does not contain key like `results`. It has `articles` key value. So `dataDictionary["results"]` is a null object.

`dataDictionary["results"]` will be null so try using `?` instead of `!`

```
let articles = dataDictionary["results"] as? [[String: Any]]
```

I think it will be

```
let articles = dataDictionary["articles"] as? [[String: Any]]
```

Comment: Didn't catch the results part, you were right, thank you.

Comment: @Modulus If this answer help you to solve this then please mark this answer as accepted.