# closure inside completion handler of URLSession.shared.dataTask

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, nsurlsession

I have a call to a closure inside a URLSession.shared.dataTask task.
The thing is that when I set a breakpoint inside my closure it won't finish executing.

```
func query(url: String, args: [String:String], completion: @escaping (_ data: Data) -> Void) {
// Create request url in order to query API.
let url = makeGetRequestUsing(url: url, args: args)
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { data, response, error in
    guard let data = data, error == nil else {
        print("error:", error ?? "")
        return
    }
    completion(data)
}

task.resume()
```

And this is how I call it.

```
self.comments = []
api.query(url: url, args: args) { data in
    let jsonData = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data)
    print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8))
    if let jsonArray = jsonData as? [[String: Any]] {
        // Create comments from the json received.
        for i in 0..<jsonArray.count {
            do {
                self.comments.append(try Comment(json: jsonArray[i]))
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.refreshComments()
        }
    }
}
```

I have set a break point inside the completion handler, and it seems that the error comes from the init of Comment class.

```
init(json: [String: Any]) throws {
// Get the comment text.
guard let comment = json[Comment.commentText] as? String else {
  throw SerializationError.missing(Comment.commentText)
}

// Get userImage.
guard let userId = json[Comment.userId] as? Int,
  let userImage = APIData.shared.getImage(url: "/userImageForId", args: ["id": String(userId)]) else {
    throw SerializationError.missing(Comment.userId)
}

// Get userename.
guard let resp = APIData.shared.getQuery(url: "/userNameForId", args: ["id": String(userId)]) as? [String: String],
  let username = resp[Comment.username] else {
    throw SerializationError.missing(Comment.username)
}

self.comment = comment
self.username = username
self.userImage = userImage
```

}

The getImage and getQuery are same as the first code. I initiate a task and wait until I get the result using a semaphore.

Comment: You are not calling task.resume() anywhere

Comment: I do so after the code above. I thought it was not necessary to include it here.

Comment: jsonData is a very misleading name for a dictionary or array

Comment: Small detail but you can avoid doing `if let` and just directly use `closure?(jsonData)`

Comment: You should do a completion handler and just pass the data `func queryServer(url: String, args: [String:String], completion: @escaping (_ data: Data?) -> Void)`

Comment: and call `completion(data)`

Comment: @LeoDabus it does not work.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? you need to add the closure to the method when you call it and deal with the asynchronously returned data there

Comment: That's exactly what I have done. The completion handler does not finish executing

Comment: so edit your question with your actual code

Comment: @LeoDabus done.

Comment: don't forget to unwrap the data `guard let data = data, error == nil else {` and it would be better to change the completion type to non optional `(_ data: Data)`

Comment: Don't forget to remove the breakpoint

Comment: Why are you casting it to NSArray? just cast it to `[String]` if it is an array of Strings

Comment: @LeoDabus changed. I removed NSArray and changed it to [Any], [String] won't work because it comment has multiple fields not just text. But it still does not work (the completion handler does not finish executing).

Comment: So you need to iterate your array of Any objects and cast to the proper type. Why don't you print the json data returned? `print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8))` do you don't have to guess

Comment: The json received is correct. The problem is that the completion handler does not finish executing it iterates once and then the closure stops executing. Actually, the completion handler from the url task also stops executing.

Comment: What's `Comment(jsonData:)`? You are passing Any but looks like you should be passing Data

Comment: @LeoDabus I have investigated a little bit. It seems the error comes from `Comment(jsonData:)` because in that init I have another NSURLDataTask which for some reason blocks the current one. Do you know how can I fix the problem ?

Comment: What problem ? Your question is totally unclear. Your error is happening in an initializer that you did not even post. How am I suppose to know how to fix it?

Comment: @LeoDabus please see now.

Comment: change the init type to Data and use JSON serialization to get the json object from this data and cast the result to `[String:Any]` Actually if you don't  show your JSON string I can only guess. I have no idea what it is comming in your json. Sorry still unclear. BTW the first part of your question it is not relevant anymore

Comment: You need to properly parse the json returned by your API. Once you have done that you can pass the proper data to your Comment initializer. BTW you should take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/a/43121890/2303865

Comment: The code was working when it was synchrounous now when it is asynchrounous I don't know why when I initiate a second nsurldatatask it cancels the first one.

Answer (score 0):

You say your closure won't finish executing and you also mentioned that you are using a semaphore somewhere in code you haven't posted. It is highly likely that you are using the semaphore incorrectly and that is blocking your thread.

There is nothing in the problem that I can see that warrants using a semaphore in the first place. By bringing in semaphores and exceptions, you seem to be making the code way more complex than necessary.

I suggest you read up on how to unit test code and build up your logic a little at a time. It looks like you are biting off more than you can chew at this time.