# Is there a way to use guard statements more concisely?

Tags: swift

I'm using [Gloss](https://github.com/hkellaway/Gloss) for my JSON instantiation. Here is a sample class:

```
public class MyObj: Decodable
{
    let id_user         : String
    let contact_addr1   : String
    let contact_addr2   : String?
    let contact_city    : String
    let contact_state   : String
    let contact_zip     : String
    let points          : Int

    // Deserialization
    required public init?(json: JSON)
    {
        guard let id_user : String = "somekey" <~~ json else {
            assertionFailure("MyObj - invalid JSON. Missing key: wouldbenicetonotwritethisforeachmember")
            return nil
        }
        guard let contact_addr1 : String = "somekey" <~~ json else {
            assertionFailure("MyObj - invalid JSON. Missing key: wouldbenicetonotwritethisforeachmember")
            return nil
        }
        guard let contact_city : String = "somekey" <~~ json else {
            assertionFailure("MyObj - invalid JSON. Missing key: wouldbenicetonotwritethisforeachmember")
            return nil
        }
        guard let contact_state : String = "somekey" <~~ json else {
            assertionFailure("MyObj - invalid JSON. Missing key: wouldbenicetonotwritethisforeachmember")
            return nil
        }
        guard let contact_zip : String = "somekey" <~~ json else {
            assertionFailure("MyObj - invalid JSON. Missing key: wouldbenicetonotwritethisforeachmember")
            return nil
        }
        guard let points : Int = "somekey" <~~ json else {
            assertionFailure("MyObj - invalid JSON. Missing key: wouldbenicetonotwritethisforeachmember")
            return nil
        }

        self.id_user        = id_user
        self.contact_addr1  = contact_addr1
        self.contact_addr2  = "somekey"     <~~ json
        self.contact_city   = contact_city
        self.contact_state  = contact_state
        self.contact_zip    = contact_zip
        self.contact_points = points
    }
}
```

I have a lot of model classes. Hundreds of members between them. Writing a multi-line guard statement for each one really junks up my code. Is there any way I can encapsulate the guard functionality into something more concise? Maybe a function or something like:

```
shortGuard("memberName", "jsonKey")
```

Maybe there is a way to guard against an array of string keys?

Comment: About using glosss. You should read the last paragraph from this https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=37.You should use a struct instead of a class and spend some time creating a custom initializer for your struct instead of using gloss. You should take a look at this also http://stackoverflow.com/a/43121890/2303865

Comment: Lots of people prefer a little abstraction to Swift's overly verbose yet barely readable default implementation. I want to avoid a billion x as? [String: Any] guard statements. The null coalescing operator (??) does let me do what I want very concisely, but it will does not allow me to do any error handling when a key is missing (this would be helpful during development).

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=37

Comment: *"...prefer a little abstraction to Swift's overly verbose..."*. I'm sorry, but this caught my eye. Have you worked with Objective-C much? Some things don't "just work" out-of-the-box with Swift, be it version 2, 3, or maybe even 4. The said, this may be the first time I heard "Swift" and "verbose" in the same sentence. :-)

Comment: Yes, Obj-C is actually less verbose and easier to read in spite of Swift's mission statement because optionals are such a mess. If you want to debate, then please make a post in the appropriate forum. You must answer my original question here.

Answer (score 1):

There are a huge variety of ways to accomplish this. They all boil down to writing a wrapper function to map your keys to values.  Here are a couple quick examples I thought of, but as I say there are many ways to do this depending on what you're after:

```
enum JSONError: Error {
    case keyNotFound(String)
}

extension JSON {
    func values<T>(for keys: [String]) throws -> [T] {
        var values = [T]()

        for key in keys {
            guard let value: T = key <~~ self else {
                throw JSONError.keyNotFound(key)
            }

            values.append(value)
        }

        return values
    }

    func values<T>(for keys: [String], closure: ((_ key: String, _ value: T) -> Void)) throws {
        for key in keys {
            guard let value: T = key <~~ self else {
                throw JSONError.keyNotFound(key)
            }

            closure(key, value)
        }
    }
}
```

The first validates all keys before you can use any of them and will throw if one isn't present.  You'd use it like so:

```
do {
    let keys = ["foo", "bar"]

    // The type of the values constant is important.
    // In this example we're saying look for values of type Int.
    let values: [Int] = try json.values(for: keys)

    for (index, key) in keys.enumerated() {
        print("value for \(key): \(values[index])")
    }
} catch JSONError.keyNotFound(let key) {
    assertionFailure("key not found \(key)")
}
```

The second one will pass back key, value pairs to a closure as they appear in your keys array and will throw at the first one it finds that doesn't exist.

```
do {
    let keys = ["foo", "bar"]

    // The type of the closure's value argument is important.
    // In this example we're saying look for values of type String.
    try json.values(for: keys) { (key, value: String) in
        print("value for key \(key) is \(value)")
    }
} catch JSONError.keyNotFound(let key) {
    assertionFailure("key not found \(key)")
}
```

Using the first version in an `init?()` function for your class, we have something like this:

```
public struct MyObj: Decodable {
    public let id_user         : String
    public let contact_addr1   : String
    public let contact_addr2   : String?
    public let points          : Int

    public init?(json: S) {
        do {
            let stringKeys = ["id_user", "contact_addr1"]
            let stringValues: [String] = try json.values(for: stringKeys)

            id_user = stringValues[0]
            contact_addr1 = stringValues[1]

            // this isn't required, so just extract with no error if it fails
            contact_addr2 = "contact_addr2" <~~ json

            let intKeys = ["points"]
            let intValues: [Int] = try json.values(for: intKeys)

            points = intValues[0]
        } catch JSONError.keyNotFound(let key) {
            assertionFailure("key \(key) not found in JSON")
            return nil
        } catch {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Now this is what I'm taking about. Please give me a minute to review. The type stuff is new to me.

Answer (score 1):

I have not used Gloss, and it mostly seems to be unnecessary considering that it is simple enough to parse JSON safely without needing an extra library, or using unfamiliar syntax.

**Option 1:**

You can group the optional unwrapping in a single `guard` statement.

Example:

```
public struct MyObj {
    let id_user         : String
    let contact_addr1   : String
    let contact_addr2   : String?
    let points          : Int

    public init?(json: Any) {
        guard 
            let entities = json as? [String : Any],
            let id_user = entities["some key"] as? String,
            let contact_addr1 = entities["some key"] as? String,
            let points = entities["some key"] as? Int
        else {
            assertionFailure("...")
            return nil
        }

        self.id_user        = id_user
        self.contact_addr1  = contact_addr1
        self.contact_addr2  = entities["some key"] as? String
        self.contact_points = points
    }
}
```

**Option 2:**

Another approach would be to eliminate the `guard` statements altogether, and let the parser throw an error during parsing, and use an optional `try` to convert the result to nil.

Example:

```
// Helper object for parsing values from a dictionary. 
// A similar pattern could be used for arrays. i.e. array.stringAt(10)
struct JSONDictionary {
    let values: [String : Any]
    init(_ json: Any) throws {
        guard let values = json as? [String : Any] else {
            throw MyError.expectedDictionary
        }
        self.values = values
    }

    func string(_ key: String) throws -> String {
        guard let value = values[key] as? String else {
            throw MyError.expectedString(key)
        }
        return value
    }

    func integer(_ key: String) throws -> Int {
        guard let value = values[key] as? Int else {
            throw MyError.expectedInteger(key)
        }
        return value
    }
}
```

Parser:

```
public struct MyObj {
    let id_user         : String
    let contact_addr1   : String
    let contact_addr2   : String?
    let points          : Int

    public init(json: Any) throws {
        // Instantiate the helper object. 
        // Ideally the JSONDictionary would be passed by the caller.
        let dictionary = try JSONDictionary(json),
        self.id_user = try dictionary.string("some key"),
        self.contact_addr1 = try dictionary.string("some key"),
        self.points = try dictionary.integer("some key")

        // Results in an optional if the string call throws an exception
        self.contact_addr2 = try? dictionary.string("some key")
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
// Instantiate MyObj from myJSON. 
// myObject will be nil if parsing fails.
let myObject = try? MyObj(json: myJSON)
```

Comment: When your `guard` in example 1 fails you can't tell which key was the failure point, and that's somewhat limiting.  In example 2 your `string()` and `integer()` functions are good examples but should not return implicitly unwrapped optionals.  Just return `String` and `Int` respectively.