# How do I parse a JSON object that has type-dependent sub-objects, in Swift?

Tags: json, swift, swift4

I have the following JSON object:

```
[{
    "type": "foo",
    "props": {
        "word": "hello"
    }
}, {
    "type": "bar",
    "props": {
        "number": 42
    }
}]
```

Depending on the type stored in `type`, the object in `props` has different keys. So, I tried with some logic

```
struct MyObject : Codable {
    struct FooProps { let word: String }
    struct BarProps { var number: Int }
    enum PropTypes { case FooProps, BarProps }

    let type: String
    let props: PropTypes?

    enum CodingKeys : CodingKey {
        case type, props
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        type = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .type)
        switch type {
        case "foo":
            props = try values.decode(FooProps.self, forKey: .props)
        case "bar":
            props = try values.decode(BarProps.self, forKey: .props)
        default:
            props = nil
        }
    }
}
```

but no luck

```
error: jsontest.playground:10:8: error: type 'MyObject' does not conform to protocol 'Encodable'
struct MyObject : Codable {
       ^

jsontest.playground:16:9: note: cannot automatically synthesize 'Encodable' because 'MyObject.PropTypes?' does not conform to 'Encodable'
    let props: PropTypes?
        ^

error: jsontest.playground:27:39: error: cannot convert value of type 'MyObject.FooProps.Type' to expected argument type 'MyObject.PropTypes?.Type'
            props = try values.decode(FooProps.self, forKey: .props)
                                      ^~~~~~~~

error: jsontest.playground:29:39: error: cannot convert value of type 'MyObject.BarProps.Type' to expected argument type 'MyObject.PropTypes?.Type'
            props = try values.decode(BarProps.self, forKey: .props)
                                      ^~~~~~~~
```

Then, I thought some class magic would probably do

```
class PropTypes : Codable { }
class FooProps : PropTypes { var word: String = "Default String" }
class BarProps : PropTypes { var number: Int = -1 }

class MyObject : Codable {
    let type: String
    var props: PropTypes?

    enum CodingKeys : CodingKey {
        case type, props
    }

    ...
```

but when I do `dump` the result of the parsing, I only get the default values

```
▿ 2 elements
  ▿ __lldb_expr_32.MyObject #0
    - type: "foo"
    ▿ props: Optional(__lldb_expr_32.FooProps)
      ▿ some: __lldb_expr_32.FooProps #1
        - super: __lldb_expr_32.PropTypes
        - word: "Default String"
  ▿ __lldb_expr_32.MyObject #2
    - type: "bar"
    ▿ props: Optional(__lldb_expr_32.BarProps)
      ▿ some: __lldb_expr_32.BarProps #3
        - super: __lldb_expr_32.PropTypes
        - number: -1
```

My question is: what am I missing? Can this be done at all?

**EDIT** Following Kevin Ballard's suggestion, I get the following errors:

```
error: jsontest.playground:15:37: error: no 'decode' candidates produce the expected contextual result type 'MyObject.FooProps'
            props = try .foo(values.decode(FooProps.self, forKey: .props))
                                    ^

jsontest.playground:15:37: note: overloads for 'decode' exist with these result types: Bool, Int, Int8, Int16, Int32, Int64, UInt, UInt8, UInt16, UInt32, UInt64, Float, Double, String, T
            props = try .foo(values.decode(FooProps.self, forKey: .props))
                                    ^

error: jsontest.playground:17:37: error: no 'decode' candidates produce the expected contextual result type 'MyObject.BarProps'
            props = try .bar(values.decode(BarProps.self, forKey: .props))
                                    ^

jsontest.playground:17:37: note: overloads for 'decode' exist with these result types: Bool, Int, Int8, Int16, Int32, Int64, UInt, UInt8, UInt16, UInt32, UInt64, Float, Double, String, T
            props = try .bar(values.decode(BarProps.self, forKey: .props))
                                    ^
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your original listed errors, there are two distinct issues.

1. You declared conformance to `Codable`, but the errors are telling you it cannot automatically synthesize `Encodable`. Your question isn't about encoding, but decoding, so for this I'd say just conform to `Decodable` instead of `Codable` (or implement encoding yourself).
2. `props` is of type `PropTypes?`, where `PropTypes` is an enum. You're decoding either `FooProps` or `BarProps`, and stuffing the result into `props`. You need to wrap the result in the enum instead. Also your enum is defined wrong, you have cases named `FooProps` and `BarProps`, which don't carry values. It should be redefined like `{ case foo(FooProps), bar(BarPros) }` instead.

So together, this would look like

```
struct MyObject : Decodable {
    struct FooProps : Decodable { let word: String }
    struct BarProps : Decodable { var number: Int }
    enum PropTypes { case foo(FooProps), bar(BarProps) }

    let type: String
    let props: PropTypes?

    enum CodingKeys : CodingKey {
        case type, props
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        type = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .type)
        switch type {
        case "foo":
            props = try .foo(values.decode(FooProps.self, forKey: .props))
        case "bar":
            props = try .bar(values.decode(BarProps.self, forKey: .props))
        default:
            props = nil
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Also your `type` property is now redundant, because you can use the `props` property to determine what the type was.

Comment: 1. Thanks, I edited the question to include the error messages I get with your proposed changes. 2. True, but I get it anyway, so might as well use it :)

Comment: @Morpheu5 Ah right, `FooProps` and `BarProps` don't conform to `Decodable`. You'll need to update those. You can probably just declare conformance and let it auto-synthesize. I'll update my code snippet to do that.

Comment: Regarding `type`, the problem with keeping it is you can then construct values where the `type` and `props` keys disagree about the actual type of the object, e.g. `MyObject(type: "wrong", props: .foo(FooProps(word: "hello")))`.

Comment: Indeed, but the actual data I am dealing with comes from a log table that is generated automatically and hardly ever changes – and when it does, it's versioned.

Comment: Regarding the `Decodable` bit: that's it. Solved. Thanks a million :D You have no idea how many hours I wasted on this, today.