# In SwiftyJSON, what is the difference between array, arrayValue and arrayObject?

Tags: json, swift, option-type, swifty-json, anyobject

I'm trying to better understand where would each have a distinct use case.

From what I understand:

- **array:** is a simple optional array.
- **arrayValue:** is a non-optional array that will return an empty array if it's `nil`
- But I can't correctly understand where would you want to use `arrayObject`?  It seems that you would use that when the entity is something other than [`JSON`](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON/blob/master/Source/SwiftyJSON.swift#L95). But I can't understand why/how something could be other than [`JSON`](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON/blob/master/Source/SwiftyJSON.swift#L95), is it about custom objects that we create ourselves?

This is the [JSON extension](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON/blob/master/Source/SwiftyJSON.swift#L747) related to arrays:

```
extension JSON {

    //Optional [JSON]
    public var array: [JSON]? {
        if self.type == .array {
            return self.rawArray.map { JSON($0) }
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }

    //Non-optional [JSON]
    public var arrayValue: [JSON] {
        return self.array ?? []
    }

    //Optional [Any]
    public var arrayObject: [Any]? {
        get {
            switch self.type {
            case .array:
                return self.rawArray
            default:
                return nil
            }
        }
        set {
            if let array = newValue {
                self.object = array as Any
            } else {
                self.object = NSNull()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Most of the time you would just use arrayObject

Comment: @LeoDabus When you're in [Canada, the 80s don't come to Canda until til like 93](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0885872/quotes/qt0453933). From the place I am at, we're just about to migrate from Swift 2.3 to Swift 3 (not 4) :(. So I would be pleased if you would still explain the differences.

Comment: Can you elaborate why most of the time you would use arrayObject? The code base I was looking into, `arrayValue` was used 5X more...

Comment: If you are just fetching values from an API you would just use arrayObject. I haven’t used SwiftyJSON since Swift 3. Read this https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=37

Comment: You might be interested in this answer also https://stackoverflow.com/a/43121890/2303865